# How does evaporation impact enthalpy calculations?

Tags: material-science, chemistry

For the following question, why should one calculated the heat transfer that occurs from going from 100°C to 36.6°C? As doesn't the water reach 100°C and then vaporize instead of coming back down to 36.6°C?

Additionally, while performing this calculation, why should the specific heat capacity of gaseous water be used instead of the specific heat capacity of liquid water? As shouldn't the specific heat capacity of liquid water be used as the state of the water while going from 100 °C - 36.6°C is liquid.

"Evaporation of sweat requires energy and thus take excess heat away from the body. Some of the water that you drink may eventually be converted into sweat and evaporate. If you drink a 20-ounce bottle of water that had been in the refrigerator at 3.8 °C, how much heat is needed to convert all of that water into sweat and then to vapor?? (Note: Your body temperature is 36.6 °C. For the purpose of solving this problem, assume that the thermal properties of sweat are the same as for water.)"

The give
Heating 567 g from 3.8 °C to 100 °C
q1= m Cp ΔT = 567g x 4.18 J/g-°C x 96.2°C = 228 kJ
Vaporizing step q2= n ΔHvap = 31.5 moles x 30.67 kJ/mole =1281 kJ
Cooling the vapor from 100 °C to 38.6 °C  q3= m Cp ΔT =567g x 1.84 x (-61.4) = -64 kJ
qTotal = q1 + q2 + q3 = 228kJ + 1281kJ -64kJ = 1445 kJ

Source:
https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Oregon_Institute_of_Technology/OIT%3A_CHE_202_-_General_Chemistry_II/Unit_8%3A_Solutions_and_Phase_Changes/8.1%3A_Heating_Curves_and_Phase_Changes/8.1%3A_Heating_Curves_and_Phase_Changes_(Problems)

Comment: So calculate the energy to heat then the energy to evaporate.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing there is 100 degrees.  Sweating isn't heating up water to boiling, this would be problematic on your life.  Evaporation can happen at any normal temperature.  This is transformation of water at 36.6 to vapor at 36.6, plus the liquid change from 3.8 to 36.6

Comment: but in the answers it says that the vapor is cooled from 100 °C to 38.6 °C? Are you implying that the answer is wrong?

Comment: if that's what it says then yes.  Maybe if you had the enthalpy of the vapor only at 100 and needed to convert it to room temp you might use it in a calculation, but nothing in that room would be 100 degrees.